# VS Code does not suggest installed npm package

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, npm

I've installed, through npm (`npm install react-native-elements --save` and `npm i --save react-native-vector-icons`) two packages in my react-native (Expo) project. But the VS Code does not suggest elements from this package and keep suggesting elements from react-native instead of react-native-elements with the same name.

Would you mind explaining to me how can I force VS code to find, suggest and import this packages.

Things I've tried:
1 - restart VS code
2 - restart computer
3 - start over again a new project and reinstall all the packages.

The following image refers to the VS Code displaying the packages correctly installed and the menu does not suggesting the same package.

[image]

I'm trying to make VS code recognize, suggest and import the installed packages through npm.

Answer (score 1):

I use an extension called 'npm Intellisense' and it works great for me! It's an addon by Christian Kohler.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I uninstalled VS code, proceed the entire configuration again and now it is working. I don't know if It is a problem with previous configuration or some VS code bug. I've done the same steps and this time it is working. Thank you Dwayne for your tip.